# Pass parameters to controller in defined route?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

Say I have an app defined as such:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myControllers'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'myTemplate.html',
            controller: 'MyController'
            //???
        })]);
```

How can I say, set `$scope.myVariable` via this route definition? I want to use this for breadcrumbs.

Answer (score 2):

I think a better way to do what you are doing is to use route parameters. See
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams

You can make your route something like
/Chapter/:chapterId

and in your controller, inject $routeParams and access the value like so:
$routeParams.chapterId

Comment: I am using routeParams in my code, I was just trying to have a simple example here. I wanted to define the values here in the config rather than separately in each controller. I am using this to populate breadcrumbs.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can use the `resolve` property in the `.when` method like so:

```
.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'myTemplate.html',
    controller: 'MyController',
    resolve: {
        test: function() {return "test";}
    }
});
```

Then in my controller I don't access it via the `$scope` but I inject it like so:

```
.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'test', function($scope, test) {
    //test contains "test"
}]);
```